# Docker Install MySQL v3.23 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker

Have inherited a **very** old site that needs a local dev environment created in Docker, which normally is really quick, but it appears it needs to have MySQL 3.23 since using MySQL 5.7 and importing the sqldump of the existing site has a bunch of issue regarding character sets, which are only easily resolved above MySQL v4.x.  So I've been trying to find the specific `apt-get` install instructions for MySQL 3.23 since there is definitely no docker hub images available.

Does anyone have a source or example for installing MySQL v3.23 on Ubuntu 16.04? or maybe I should just keep working on figure out the character set issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! The last release of MySQL 3.23 was 2003-09-11, which is 14 years ago as we type this. Oracle has done its best to remove all unsupported versions from official download sites.

You might find old copies of MySQL 3.23 binaries and source floating around on obscure sites in lesser-known corners of the internet.

I don't expect the binaries can run on modern OS versions. The runtime shared libraries are just the wrong versions. You'd have to compile MySQL 3.23 from source.

Even finding the source is hard. I found a copy of 3.23.49 here: http://live.dadanini.at/mysql/downloads_html/mysql-3.23.html

(3.23.49 was released 2002-02-14, 19 months before the last version 3.23.58, dated 2003-09-11).

I spun up a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 16.04 and installed:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y --reinstall build-essential libncurses5-dev
```

I got the MySQL source to configure... sort of. It wouldn't recognize the pthreads option, so I tried to use mit-threads instead:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --enable-large-files --enable-shared=yes --with-mit-threads --with-innodb
```

But it ran into errors trying to configure mit-threads:

```
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

configure: error: System type  not recognized or not supported.
See ./config/configure.in for supported systems.
```

That's right, the mit-threads code is so old, it doesn't support 64-bit architecture on Linux!!

I'm not going to download a Vagrant box for 32-bit Ubuntu, if such a thing can even be found.

I'm giving up at this point. You are welcome to continue trying! :-)

I have to comment that software that is so old has had *hundreds* of severe security bugs fixed over the years. I wouldn't recommend using the software except temporarily to help serve as a source for ETL of the data into a more current RDBMS.

If I were you, I would invest the time instead into figuring out the character set issue so you could import directly into MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely work towards that instead.  I was able to convert it from latin1 to UTF-8 using `iconv -f latin1 -t UTF8 database.sql > database-utf8.sql` but the import throws the same error as the original.  I'm a bit out of my depth trying to figure out the character set issues.  Even in the sites PhpMyAdmin the characters don't show up properly so I can't even peak at the actual value which is a bit frustrating.

Comment: Seems the conversion worked, but it was related to unrenderable characters being set as default values for a bunch of columns.  So for development only I removed the default values from the columns containing this character and the import worked.  Thanks your help and getting me to change directions

Comment: Glad to help! Now I can get back to building my steam-powered car engine. ;-)